# Artifactory stop responding

Tags: artifactory

Logging in web console - Turn with no response and deployment can't pull images anymore
After analyzing log of ha primary node and ha member, here is what I see.

> replicaset : ha-primary-0
>
> [s.b.c.RemoteBinaryProvider:302] [art-exec-263 ] - sharding-cluster.remote.xxx-artifactory-ha-member-0 Unable to execute ping request to Remote endpoint at http://localhost:8046/artifactory/binarystore : Read timed out
>
> replicaset : ha-member-0
>
> 2020-12-23T08:58:05.752L [35m[tomct][0m [SEVERE] [                ] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder writeResponse] - An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:91)
>
> Solution : restart members (pod) by scaling down replicasets.

Environnement :
Openshift 4.6.8 in aws with posgtress rds database.
Kubernetes 1.19

What can I try ?

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please check whether the *block quote* covers the correct part of your post. Please have your spelling checker check English spelling when posting to an "English site". (Then again, posgtress isn't French, is it?)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your volumes, PVC and PV. Usually I/O errors refer to storage issues.
Try opening a terminal on the pod cd to mounted volume dir and try to write a new file

Comment: Pv seem accessible.  I succeed to write a file in the mountPath where the data resides :
/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory and I succeed to read the file /artifactory_bootstrap/binarystore.xml in both pod primary and member.

If I call the service in member node :
http://localhost:8046/artifactory/binarystore ==> Got no answer.

Comment: I replaced the default liveness probe be it returned a OK status.    

  livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /router/api/v1/system/health
              port: 8082
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 10
   
I replaced with this probe :
  livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /artifactory/api/system/ping
              port: 8081
              scheme: HTTP

Comment: With this probe, the service will restart automatically and I will know exactly when the problem happen.
I does not solve de problem but it will decrease the downtime.
I tough it could be the result of a cron task.  I ran all the tasks manually and no problem.